# Can a button in a table view row be indexed somehow?

Tags: xcode, button, tableview

I have a table view with 3 items, one of which I have behind a button.  When the button is selected, I want to hide that button, revealing the item behind it.  I am displaying the table row using a table view cell.  When I select the one button to hide, scrolling through the table hides more buttons.  The hiding of the button seems to hide a button based on some location within the viewable rows of the current view.  I'm trying to hide the button on a specific row.

I can write to the NSLog whenever I hit the code to hide a button and I will only get there once, but as I scroll through the table, the hidden attribute for the button applies to other rows that come into view.  If I select the button on row 53 I want only the button in row 53 hidden, not buttons on other rows in the 120 row table.

Has anyone ever done what I am trying to do?  Any help I can get to figure out what is happening would be appreciated.  Thanks.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *ElementCellIdentifier = @"ElementCellIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:ElementCellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ElementRowCell"
                                                 owner:self options:nil];
        if ([nib count] > 0) {
            cell = self.tvCell;
        } else {
            NSLog(@"failed to load ElementRowCell nib file!");
        }
    }

    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];

    UILabel *atomic_number = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1];                               
    atomic_number.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",elements_table[row].atomic_number];

    UILabel *element_name = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:2];
    element_name.text = [NSString stringWithCString:elements_table[row].element_name];

    UILabel *element_symbol = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:3];
    element_symbol.text = [NSString stringWithCString:elements_table[row].element_symbol];

    return cell;
}

- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender {

NSLog(@"Getting to buttonPressed from row button");
UIButton *pressedButton = (UIButton *)sender;
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.mainTableView indexPathForCell:     (UITableViewCell *)[sender superview]];
pressedButton.hidden = TRUE;
```

}

Comment: Not sure why you are getting this result. Please post `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` and the action method which hides the button(s).

Comment: I'm new to this forum.  I'm exceeding the number of allowable characters in this comment field.  How can I post my code?

Comment: You add your code by editing your question. Just below the text of your question are your question tags, immediately below that you should see a link marked edit click that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry.
Basically what's happening is you are hiding the instance of the button in that specific table view cell. The problem is when it gets dequeue'd for another row nothing is restoring it's state. And if you were to just restore it's state to visible then the rows you clicked would be forgotten. You will need to save the rows that have been clicked already to be able to properly restore state in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

How I would handle this is declare an `NSMutableSet *selectedIndexPaths;`. And use this to store the rows I have selected. Then when the button is clicked add that indexPath to the set like so.

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)button{
    if (![button isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) return;
    UIView *finder = button.superview;
    while ((![finder isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) && finder != nil) {
        finder = finder.superview;
    }
    if (finder == nil) return;
    UITableViewCell *myCell = (UITableViewCell *)finder;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.mainTableView indexPathForCell:myCell];
    [selectedIndexPaths addObject:indexPath];
    button.hidden = TRUE;
    NSLog(@"IndexPathRow %d",indexPath.row);
}
```

Now to properly restore state when scrolling in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` use an if statement to set the button's hidden property, like so:

```
buttonPropertyName.hidden = ([selectedIndexPaths containsObject:indexPath]);
```

Comment: That does hide the button I click, but when I scroll the view, there are other buttons that get hidden.  When I scroll back to where I started, the button that was hidden is no longer hidden.  But other random buttons are. Very strange.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I will give that a try.  Unfortunately, I have to leave now and won't be able to get back to this until this evening most likely, but I will let you know if I get it to work.  Thanks again.

Comment: Is indexPathForCell something I should have declared already?  I'm getting an "undeclared" error.

Comment: Sorry.  This is my first attempt at using tables and I'm still confused.  Am I supposed to have the indexPathForCell declared?  My table view is named tableView but when I use the code in your example, I get a syntax error because of the indexPathForCell reference in buttonPressed.

Comment: You may need to add self.tableView. No, you don't have to declare it. You need to use whatever name you have given your table view property. If you have not already created an IBOutlet property on your view controller for our table view that could be the problem.

Comment: I changed my buttonPressed method.  Current one is shown above.  My button is getting hidden properly now.  But I can't figure out how to get the actual row for the cell that had the button chosen.  I need to use it as an index.

Comment: I tried that and the following always displays 0 for the row:

    NSInteger row = indexPath.row;
    NSLog(@"Row is %d", row);

Comment: Are you suggesting I put that NSLog where in buttonPressed?  When I do, I get a syntax error - "request for member superview in something not a structure or union".  And if the button is a sub view of the label, how do I fix it?  I didn't intend that to happen.

Comment: Yes, buttonPressed is where I am getting row 0;  The NSLog entry is:


2012-01-22 00:28:09.418 elements1[31583:207] <UITableViewCellContentView: 0x60009f0; frame = (0 0; 320 43); layer = <CALayer: 0x6000a20>>

There was something about moving this to chat.  Don't know how that works but will do that if you want.

Comment: FYI - the following works if I select the row the botton is on, and the row is the value I expect and would want if the button is pressed.

    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
  didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
 NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
 NSLog(@"Row is %d", row);
 
}

Comment: I got it working with the following:
    
    // Get the cell
    UITableViewCell *myCell = (UITableViewCell *)pressedButton.superview.superview;
 
 // Get the row
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.mainTableView indexPathForCell:myCell];

 NSInteger row = [indexPath row];
 NSLog(@"Row is %d", row);

    pressedButton.hidden = TRUE;

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Edited in response to comment, with this edit it will not matter where in the view hierarchy the button is as long as it is at some-point a subview of a UITableViewCell.